Telegram MiniApp: How do I share media to users from within the MiniAPP?
Telegram MiniAPP shareMessage
I see that telegram has added shareMessage and I tried using this method to send a message with an image that I wanted to provide. But I cannot find any examples and I see that the method needs to prepare a message, then send a message with msgId.
Reviewing the documentation I found nothing on this subject. Has anyone done it already and can help me figure out how to use shareMessage? I don't see this method here either: https://docs.telegram-mini-apps.com/platform/methods.
Note that I have already stored the image and I have a public url for the image as well. If needed, I can also provide the Blob of the image.
Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps
